# Django: I want a Queryset as a list. How?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset, backend

I need to get a Queryset in Django and make a copy of it as a variable in the form of a list of dictionaries. I thought this is what Querysets were, I guess I'm wrong.

```
listA = User_Item.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(id=1))
```

Gives me an error when I try to perform a simple algorithm with it.
I don't want to interact with the database- I need to copy that Queryset as a list of dictionaries, so I can display modified versions of the lists without actually changing the data. How do I do this?

(Trying to get a list of entries in this join table, which should be a list of dictionaries with dictionaries for some of the key values)

Comment: You can use [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) with lambda expression.

Comment: go with `values() or values_list()` its very good for db performance but a but ugly to handle sometimes since everything is hardcoded.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: values(), won't that just get a list of values from the object? I could but it'll be a bit harder to work with in the template. I'm trying to copy the Queryset as it is - a list of dictionaries(objects).

Answer (score 1):

To make a list from a query set just pass it to the list function `list_a = list(queryset)`. That will return you a list with the objects from the queryset. If you want that as a dict you can call the `values()` method on the queryset before passing it to the list: `list(queryset.values())`

Answer (score -1):

Both `values()` and `values_list()` return a `queryset object`, which should be fine for most cases. But if you do want to have a list, then as the previous answer states you will have to typecast it to a list using the function `list(queryset)`

Typecasting to queryset to a list will remove some performance gained just by using the queryset.